# asp.net mvc 4 routing error

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

im currently making an website in asp.net c#, using windows azure with a database, when i push the files to the server it works perfectly, the weird thing is every time i click the play button i get this error. it got to a point where having to keep sending it to the server to preview got annoying, if anyone could help me resolve this would greatly appreciate. also i have read up about "Area registration" and have attempted many ways but none seems to work. this is my RouteConfig.cs

```
   public class RouteConfig
    {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
name: "View",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        ); 
      } 
    }
```

when i edit url:

```
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

and put url:

```
  "Views/Home/{action}/{id}"
```

the directory just loads, allowing me to manually select files, the error dosnt come up, but the index cant be access, when i click Views, it then becomes " localhost - /Views/" but the page stays the same, i click "views" again and i get a 404 "Requested URL: /Views/Views/"

This is the error i am receiving :

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.

The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched     
locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web      
request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where  
it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' or its master was   
not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations 
were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.   
Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using   
the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view     
engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml]
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) +355958
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +121
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext    
controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter,    
ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext    
controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +89
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult  
asyncResult) +102
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult  
asyncResult) +43
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)  
+14
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult 
asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
+25
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult 
result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  
+9629296
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&  
completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET   
Version:4.0.30319.18034
```

Answer (score 1):

To simply add view:

Right mouse button inside HomeController Index action and choose "add View".

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things you are missing the index.cshtml file.

In your project you could have a views folder in the same level as your controller folder. In that there should be a folder **with the same name as the controller minus "controller" text.**  Index.cshtml needs to exist in there.